# Why do the client and server sides of StackExchange use different abbreviations for time spans?

Tags: bug, status-completed, live-refresh, timestamps

When I load a StackExchange site, the questions on the main page show up with timestamps like "answered 5m ago joeuser": [image: 7m ago]

But after a minute ticks by, all the timestamps get recalculated and are shown with different abbreviations for the time spans (like "answered 6 mins ago joeuser"): [image: 8 mins ago]

The new lengths often cause the page to reflow like something meaningful has been changed.

Is this a (very small) bug, or is there some good reason for it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well that sucks! We have no clue why it's different - I'm sure at some point there was a reason. In the next build the base page will also use the "mins" format like other question lists to.

Answer (score 8):

`span` elements with the class `relativetime` are found by [this js](http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/full.en.js), which includes

```
return e.minutes+" mins ago"
```

Thus why the conversion to `n mins ago`. Server-side, the short notation is being output: e.g., `nm ago`.

I think the two should be **consistent**, where I'd personally *prefer* the formatting currently implemented client-side.