# Search results page still uses inconsistent time abbreviations

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, live-refresh, timestamps

This is either a regression or an unnoticed special case of [Why do the client and server sides of StackExchange use different abbreviations for time spans?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246092/) and [Inconsistent time format on front pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248254/)

When a search page [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20java%20) first loads, the relative time is abbreviated in one way (m for minutes); when the timestamps refresh after a minute, they are abbreviated differently (min[s] for minutes).

#### Before and After:

**before** [image: before] **after** [image: after]

Comment: Both versions (‘3m’ and ‘3 mins’) are wrong. The unit symbol for ‘minute’ is ‘min’ and it shall remain unaltered in the plural. Do not forget the space between the numerical value and the unit symbol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Time formats will match as soon as builds rev `2015.2.18.3088` on meta and `2015.2.18.2308` on sites roll out.